# fetchInvoicesByOffice is not a function RTK QUERY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm having an issue with calling an auto created hook by Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query (RTKQ). The issue I get is the following: "fetchInvoicesByOffice is not a function"

Store

```js
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { InvoiceSlice } from "./Invoices/InvoiceSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [InvoiceSlice.reducerPath]: InvoiceSlice.reducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(InvoiceSlice.middleware),
  }
);
```

Slice

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from 
"@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const InvoiceSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "InvoiceSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://INVOICES_API:8081/api/",
  }),
  tagTypes: ["Invoices"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    fetchInvoices: builder.query({
      query: () => "GetAllInvoices",
      providesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    fetchInvoice: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `GetInvoice/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    fetchInvoicesByOffice: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `GetAllInvoices_ByOffice/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    addInvoiceComment: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: "addComment",
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    updateInvoicesStatus: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: "values",
        method: "PUT",
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    AddMatter: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: "UpdateMatter",
        method: "PUT",
        body: data,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
    fetchInvoice: builder.query({
      query: (id) => `GetComment/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["Invoices"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useFetchInvoicesQuery,
  useFetchInvoiceQuery,
  useFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery,
  useAddInvoiceCommentMutation,
  useUpdateInvoicesStatusMutation,
} = InvoiceSlice;
```

Component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./InvoiceList";
import "./InvoiceList.css";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import { css } from "glamor";
import {
  useFetchInvoicesQuery,
  useLazyFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery,
} from "../../features/Invoices/InvoiceSlice";

const InvoiceList = () => {
  const { data, refetch } = useFetchInvoicesQuery();
  const [fetchInvoicesByOffice, { currentData }] =
    useLazyFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  const [rowClicked, setRowClicked] = useState(0);
  const [office, setOffice] = useState("ALL");
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState("ALL");
  const [invoiceStatus, setInvoiceStatus] = useState();
  const [matter, setMatter] = useState("");
  const loggedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  const [invoicesState, setInvoicesState] = useState([]);
  const [term, setTerm] = useState("");
  const [userid, setUserId] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserId(loggedUser);
    setInvoicesState(data);
  }, [data]);

  let toastId = null;
  const displayToast = (message) => {
    if (!toast.isActive(toastId)) {
      toastId = toast(`${message} !!! `, {
        className: css({
          background: "#9e007e !important",
          color: "white !important",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        }),
        autoClose: 1000,
        closeOnClick: true,
        toastId: "my_toast",
        autoClose: true,
        closeButton: false,
        position: toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      });
    }
  };

  const onSearchSubmit = (term) => {
    setTerm(term);
  };

  const handleOfficeClick = async (offc) => {
    setOffice(offc);

    if (office === "ALL") {
      refetch();
      setInvoicesState(data);
    } else {
      setOffice((prevState) => {
        fetchInvoicesByOffice(prevState);
        setInvoicesState(currentData);

        return !prevState;
      });
      // await fetchInvoicesByOffice(offc);
      // await setInvoicesState(currentData);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (office === "ALL") {
      setOffice(office);
      fetchInvoicesByOffice("ALL");
    } else {
      setOffice(office);
      fetchInvoicesByOffice(office);
    }
  }, [office]);
```

I want to be able to use the hook in either the `useEffect` hook callback or the `handleOfficeClick` handler...........................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RTKQ query hook itself is what calls the endpoint and its return value is the fetched data and associated metadata.

See [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) for more details. Here's a query hook's function signature.

> ```
> type UseQuery = (
>   arg: any | SkipToken,
>   options?: UseQueryOptions
> ) => UseQueryResult
>
> type UseQueryOptions = {
>   pollingInterval?: number
>   refetchOnReconnect?: boolean
>   refetchOnFocus?: boolean
>   skip?: boolean
>   refetchOnMountOrArgChange?: boolean | number
>   selectFromResult?: (result: UseQueryStateDefaultResult) => any
> }
>
> type UseQueryResult<T> = {
>   // Base query state
>   originalArgs?: unknown // Arguments passed to the query
>   data?: T // The latest returned result regardless of hook arg, if present
>   currentData?: T // The latest returned result for the current hook arg, if present
>   error?: unknown // Error result if present
>   requestId?: string // A string generated by RTK Query
>   endpointName?: string // The name of the given endpoint for the query
>   startedTimeStamp?: number // Timestamp for when the query was initiated
>   fulfilledTimeStamp?: number // Timestamp for when the query was completed
>
>   // Derived request status booleans
>   isUninitialized: boolean // Query has not started yet.
>   isLoading: boolean // Query is currently loading for the first time. No data yet.
>   isFetching: boolean // Query is currently fetching, but might have data from an earlier request.
>   isSuccess: boolean // Query has data from a successful load.
>   isError: boolean // Query is currently in an "error" state.
>
>   refetch: () => void // A function to force refetch the query
> }
> ```

If you want wanting to intentionally trigger a query/fetch in a callback then you are looking for the [lazy queries](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery). These return an array that includes a "trigger function".

> ```
> const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] =
>   api.endpoints.getPosts.useLazyQuery(options);
> ```

From your API slice export the generated

```js
export const {
  useFetchInvoicesQuery,
  useFetchInvoiceQuery,
  useFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery,
  useLazyFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery, // <-- lazy query
  useAddInvoiceCommentMutation,
  useUpdateInvoicesStatusMutation,
} = InvoiceSlice;
```

Import the lazy query hook in the UI and use the returned trigger function.

```js
...
import {
 ...,
 useLazyFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery,
} from "../../features/Invoices/InvoiceSlice";

const InvoiceList = () => {
  const { data, refetch } = useFetchInvoicesQuery();
  const [fetchInvoicesByOffice] = useLazyFetchInvoicesByOfficeQuery();

  const handleOfficeClick = async (offc) => {
    await setChecked((old) => !old);
    await setOffice(offc);
    await fetchInvoicesByOffice(office);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInvoicesByOffice(office);
    if (office === "ALL") refetch();
  }, [office]);

  ...
```

Comment: Hi Drew.  I implemented the lazyFetch approach, but it is not working.  I made the changes to mirror what you did and the result still the same.

Comment: @cruz Interesting. Think you could create a ***running*** codesandbox demo of the code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: i doubt i could since it is using an internal api to fetch the data.

Comment: Use a mock data source like the JSON placeholder API.

Comment: One thing i did not use was this:   const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] =
  api.endpoints.getPosts.useLazyQuery(options);  where do i put his?  Inside the slice?

Comment: @cruz `const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] = useLazyQuery(options);` is quoted from the Redux-Toolkit documentation, e.g. it's their code example of using the lazy hook that shows what is returned, namely the "trigger" function. The latter half of the answer is the code relevant to you, that's your code using the suggested lazy query hook.

Comment: Hi Drew.  Thanks for all your help so far.  i refactored the code per your suggestion and its seems to be working fine, but in order to get the new state i have to double click to get it to refresh correctly.  Please see above updated JSX

Comment: @cruz React state updates are processed asynchronously, so setting the `office` state in a function won't have the *updated* value available to it in the same scope until the function completes and returns and React can rerender the component with the updated state. This is why you have to click a second time to have the correct updated `office` state in scope. You should just use the passed `offc` argument in the callback functions since that is what you are updating the state to.

Comment: @cruz The `office` state is initially a String, so toggling it in one of the callbacks is really strange behavior IMO. Also, the `setOffice` callback function should be a pure function, it shouldn't be calling the query trigger or other state setter functions.

Comment: Thanks Drew.  Do you mind showing me how to do this in the code?  i'm still learning react / javascript and some of these concepts are still alluding me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255063/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-cruz).

Comment: Thanks for your help Drew.  Looks like your suggestion to use a lazyQuery was the way to go.